# Does using the * operator on a pointer create a copy?

Tags: c++

I've been curious about this for some time. Say we have the following cases for accessing a data member of a class stored in dynamically allocated memory:

```c
class C {
public :
    C() = default; 
    int a = 4; 
}

int main () {
    C * ptr = new C(); 
    std::cout << "pointer->::" << ptr->a << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "dereference*().::" << (*ptr).a << std::endl; 
}
```

I'm sure the pointer method is the preferred method, and my guess is that dereferencing the pointer provides a reference, at least in C++. But in C, where there are no references (and assuming appropriate modifications to convert the class to a struct etc), would dereferencing and accessing the member like this result in a temporary shallow copy? Is this something that the compiler optimizes out?

Comment: There is no copy involved. *Dereferencing* a pointer [works the same](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access) in C: "*the result is an lvalue expression that designates the pointed-to object.*". The two forms `ptr->a` and `(*ptr).a` are entirely equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both C and C++, `*p` (dereferencing) and `p->m` (member access through pointer) are ["lvalue expressions"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/value_category). An lvalue "evaluates to the object identity". `*p` or `p->m` does not (by itself) create a copy, it refers to a variable that already exists.

Comment: Ahhhhh that's making sense. Thank you very much for your answer, this clears it up for me.

Answer (score 1):

Dereferencing a pointer does not create a copy neither for `C` neither for `C++`.
**The result of a dereferencing operation is a lvalue that describe a pointed object.**
But in any case the behaviour is the same for C and C++.